# How to compare dates based on week

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am using twig to generate a list like this

```
  {% set current_date = 0 %}
  {% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.created_at|date("m Y") != current_createdat %}
      {% set current_createdat = post.created_at|date("m Y") %}
     <h1>{{post.created_at|date("m Y")}}</h1>
    {% endif %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I compare if dates are in the same week in twig ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the week number resulted by the date filter, as example:

```
    {% if date1|date("W") == date2|date("W") %}
      Same week
    {% else %}
     week are different
    {% endif %}
```

From the doc of [php date filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> W ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP
> 4.1.0)

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the note of @qooplmao

For better comparison (including the year of the week) is better use the filter `oW` as described in [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#106974) on the doc.

So is better use this:

```
    {% if date1|date("oW") == date2|date("oW") %}
      Same week
    {% else %}
     week are different
    {% endif %}
```

Hope this help

Comment: `{% if date1|date("Y W") == date2|date("Y W") %}` would be better as it includes the year in the formatted string. Otherwise week 40 of 1950 would be classed as the same as week 40 of 2000 (and many other, obviously).

Comment: Hi @qooplmao Thanks for the note!. I see a comment about this that suggest to use `o` instead of `Y`for year comparison, [here](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#106974) the detailed motivation.  What do you think about?